# How to compare list of string with enum string values without Map or switch case?

Tags: java, enums

In Enum i defined string values like

```
public enum Rara{
  MA_ON("MO"),
  MA_MAN("MG", "PH"),
  MA_IP("MG", "PH", "IC"),
  BAR("RC");
  Rara(String... s){
       //What here?
  }
  public Rara getValue(List<Val> v){
        //What here?
  }
}
```

From front end i am getting data like

```
<val>MO<val>
<val>PH</val>  <--- This shall return MA_MAN from Enum
```

or we get data like

```
<val>MO</val> <---- This shall return MA_ON
```

Is there any tweak to do inside enum itself without using Map or switchcase but only with value parameters

so that i supply say List and it should return appropriate Enum Value?

Comment: DId you try just calling the constructor with an array of values? Something like `Rara r = new Rara(values);`.

Comment: You can't call `enum` constructor directly.

Comment: @talex Thanks for the clarification. What can you do instead?

Comment: I am a bit confused, do you want to parse the data coming from the frontend or do you want to provide data in a different format to the frontend?

Comment: @JoãoDias: Data comes either MGST or comes in group of Two or Three or four from front end or from anywhere. I will have LIst in my hand. I jus want to pass that in enum and enum shall return results. 

Values are already defined inside Enum("MGST") or Enum("",""). So i just want to do tweak within enum so it shall return value based on values i supply. Is it possible?

Comment: @talex: Even if i write method within enum. How can this achievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public enum Rara {
    MAG_STRIPE_ONLY("MGST"),
    MAG_STRIPE_MANUAL("MGST", "PHYS"),
    MAG_STRIPE_MANUAL_CHIP("MGST", "PHYS", "CICC"),
    BARCODE("BRCD");

    Rara(String... codes) {
        this.codes = List.of(codes);
    }

    private List<String> codes;

    public static Optional<Rara> getValue(List<String> values){
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(rara -> rara.codes.stream().anyMatch(values::contains))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

You basically need to iterate over the list of codes for each `Rara` and check if they match any of the provided `values`. If they do you simply return the first one (`Optional` because you might find none). Without further requirements on what to do when to find multiple `Rare` matches or what to do if none is found, this is the best we can suggest to you.

---

Given that you want a full match between `values` and `codes`, you need to use another `filter` predicate as follows:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public enum Rara {
    MAG_STRIPE_ONLY("MGST"),
    MAG_STRIPE_MANUAL("MGST", "PHYS"),
    MAG_STRIPE_MANUAL_CHIP("MGST", "PHYS", "CICC"),
    BARCODE("BRCD");

    Rara(String... codes) {
        this.codes = List.of(codes);
    }

    private List<String> codes;

    public static Optional<Rara> getValue(List<String> values){
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(rara -> rara.codes.containsAll(values))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

The code bellow shows that this is in fact working:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("MGST", "PHYS")));  
              // Optional[MAG_STRIPE_MANUAL]

        System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("MGST")));  
              // Optional[MAG_STRIPE_ONLY]
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/uGj1vV).

Comment: List.of(codes) <- which package are you referring here?

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.List`? I will add the imports to make them clearer.

Comment: Actually it says "The method of(String[]) is undefined for the type List". Using Java 8

Comment: Using this -> this.codes = Arrays.asList(codes); ... let c

Comment: No it doesnt work correctly when i search .getValueOfData(Arrays.asList("MGST", "PHYS")).get()...It should return MANUAL but it returning ONLY

Comment: Ok, the `values` List must match the `code` List, is that it?

Comment: Right. It must match the code list. allMatch() also not wroked.

Comment: This is Giving same results

Comment: Please try again. I've changed a line to `.filter(rara -> rara.codes.containsAll(values))`. This is working as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239612/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-joao-dias).

Answer (score 1):

Only way is to iterate trough `Rara.value` and compare lists.

Comment: now if i keep enum intact then how can i fetch those three values inside it. for(Rara tc: Rara.values()) {
  System.out.println(tc.name());
  System.out.println(tc.ordinal());
 }

Comment: Looks like i need map